# Find out number of lines for a string with a font in a rect?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview

I want to find out how many lines a string will have when set to a font inside a rect. Is there a way to do this?

I have this code, but i'm trying to make it process that little bit faster, as it's being used a lot in a scroll view:

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(MESSAGE_FRAME.size.width - 16, 1000000);

    CGSize expectedSize = [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Crimson" size:15]
                              constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                                  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

return expectedSize.height;
```

I know this returns line height:

```
NSLog(@"%f", [[UIFont fontWithName:@"Crimson" size:15] lineHeight]);
```

So if I can multiply that by another value, it might prove to be faster.

Comment: doesn't expectedSize.height / font lineHeight give you a reasonable result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of an alternative, and I doubt that there is one which will be much more efficient (after all, what possible magic could get to a line count and avoid the word wrap computation?).

Anyway, rather than hurt our brains shaving cycles off the computation, consider whether it needs to be done over and over while the view scrolls.   My guess is no.

I think the way to speed this up is to do the traditional size computation and cache the result.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a different way but I have a small suggestion that I did in a similar case in a table view. If your data are stored somewhere (in my case I receive text from a network and store it in a database), I calculate the size using this way only the first time the text is received and then store this answer. When loading the data I put the sizes in an array so I can retrieve the values fast.

Just a suggestion, I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS7 and above, the [officially sanctioned way](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html) is to use TextKit:

```
func numberOfLinesForString(string: String, size: CGSize, font: UIFont) -> Int {
    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(string: string, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font])

    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: size)
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0

    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    layoutManager.textStorage = textStorage
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)

    var numberOfLines = 0
    var index = 0
    var lineRange : NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0)
    for (; index < layoutManager.numberOfGlyphs; numberOfLines++) {
        layoutManager.lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex(index, effectiveRange: &lineRange)
        index = NSMaxRange(lineRange)
    }

    return numberOfLines
}
```